# conditional where condition in Spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: spring-jdbc

I have to include or exclude where condition in **Spring JDBC Template** depending upon value in parameter.
Like we do in **hibernate using 'Conjunction'** and checking if searchParam have value or not then only go for WHERE other wise return whole data.

One way is to write multiple if blocks and appending string in query suggest other ways.

I am using namedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring JDBC Template doesn't support dynamic where clause, you have to  write multiple if blocks. Something like this:

```
 NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
        MapSqlParameterSource parms = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1='X'";
        if(column2 != null){
            query += " and column2 = :column2 " ;
            parms.addValue("column2 ", column2 );
        }
        if(column3 != null){
            query += " and column3 = :column3 ";
            parms.addValue("column3 ", column3 );
        }

        List li = template.queryForList(query, parms);
```

Comment: ac to ur answer and if column1 is also null so in this case i may have to write nested if too, to include WHERE in query, i think it will become complicated to read.Cant we have some different solution Creating a class like conjunction of Hibernate with some generic code. Help.

Comment: then how do you handle aList= getJdbcTemplate().query(query, params, new  DataMapper()); this will throw SQLException while trying to map the resultset data with bean.